# How can I position a new column on rails 4 migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have been trying to migrate a new change in the db schema and struggling to get it working.

I am trying to add a new column but after another column in the db. here is what I have been doing:

Dropping the column migration:

```
class RemoveMixFromProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :profiles, :mix
  end
end
```

Adding the column back in but trying to get into certain position:

```
class AddMixToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :profiles, :mix, :string :after => :interview
  end
end
```

When i run `rake db:migrate` in the schema it does not add it after interview column.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: But why do you want the column on specific sequence?

Comment: Did you forgot a coma after `:string`?

Comment: Seems like you are missing a coma after `:string` as @BenjaminSinclaire mentioned.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Just to confirm, the :after option only works against a MySQL DB,  PG doesn't allow this

Comment: its a mysql db, the reason I am changing the position is because I am having issues with pg on my production site. I have got 3 fields that are strings for some reason the field 'mix' is at the end of the schema. When I try adding and saving anything to the db in the mix field I get a site error on the nginx server, when I add it in my local site its fine so I am just trying a work around to see if this helps.

Comment: Unless you generate SQL by hand and leave out the columns for the `INSERT` (which you should never do, for exact this kind of problems and a couple of other ones) the order of the columns is certainly not the problem. Have a look into the `production.log` to get a clue what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a migration on Postresql. The only way I know of is to drop the database entirely and change the original migration where the table is created, then create the database again and run the migration. Then you can add the fields in the order you want. However, I don't recommend this.